# Is there a Raspberry Pi "hardware-based security key"?

Tags: security

I am reading through a recent StackOverflow blog post entitled "[Security considerations for OTA software updates for IOT gateway devices](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/12/14/security-considerations-for-ota-software-updates-for-iot-gateway-devices/?cb=1)" and it got me thinking about applications for the Raspberry Pi. Specifically, in the discussion of Client-side considerations, the author makes the following statement:

> Given that client devices are often deployed into hostile networking environments with little control of physical security available to device vendors, using hardware-based security keys should be strongly considered.

My understanding of this is that a hardware-based key should be created for the device so that the key cannot be changed (as it could be if, for example, the key were simply saved in the filesystem). What hardware-based value could be used to generate such a key on the Raspberry Pi? And how would you use it to generate a key?

**EDIT** In response to @jsotola's comment:

A search for "what is a hardware based security key?" returns a list of links to devices like the Yubikey for 2FA which are probably not relevant to this discussion. While a company producing an Internet of Things (IOT) device *could* add a hardware dongle (or perhaps a "HAT") that would provide similar functionality, I believe that a removable piece of hardware is less desirable (due to cost and due to the increased possibility of tampering).

My understanding is that, with respect to the blog post cited above, the point is to generate a key based on some feature of the IOT device - perhaps a serial number or other hardware identifier which is unique to the device and cannot be changed - and to use that key for authentication when requesting over-the-air (OTA) hardware updates (which was the subject of the original blog post).

In the case of the Raspberry Pi, is there a value (or values) exposed that could be used to generate a unique (per device) security key for this kind of security?

Comment: maybe you should first ask, and research, `what is a hardware based security key?`

Comment: Are you searching for a Physically Unclonable function (PUF)?